# Expression in service activator doesn't execute (Spring Integration)

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I debug my app and the expression doesn't execute.

```
<bean id="remover" class="org.example.Remover"/>
<bean id="key" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="KEY"/>
</bean>
<integration:service-activator input-channel="middleChannel"  
expression="@remover.remove(key)"/>
```

No Exception. method doesn't call.

Answer (score 1):

That’s not true: there must be an exception. You don’t show the whole flow to determine the part who swallows your exception on the matter.

Your expression is like:

```
@remover.remove(key)
```

You correctly call `remover` bean, but there is no such a property like `key` in the `Message` object - just only `headers` and `payload`. That’s why I’m making a conclusion that you have problems.

You can turn on debug logs for the Spring Integration category and follow you the trace of the call.